# What is the difference between using multiple append function and single append function

Tags: javascript, html

I am very confused how the append function works. After I tried using append 3 times, It shows very different from single append function.

In javascript (Append 1 time)

```
var divStep = $("#stepTab");
divStep.append('<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"><input type="checkbox" />Test</div>');
```

In javascript (Append 3 times)

```
var divStep = $("#stepTab");
divStep.append('<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;">');
divStep.append('<input type="checkbox" />Test');
divStep.apend('</div>');
```

In html

```
<div id="stepTab">
</div>
```

I found that the append 1 time method worked well as I expected. The another one is very baffling.
Please can someone explain me a little bit about the difference of these 2 methods? I tried to search on the internet but I can't even know a keyword for the search.
I'm very poor in English. So sorry if it is an ambiguous question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When appending, you should be working with fully enclosed HTML because jQuery will convert them into objects. Appending is not used for HTML strings—in your second example, jQuery will simply wrap the first division element and then append the input outside of it (i.e. as a sibling).

Comment: Thank you so much for this valuable answer.

Comment: jQuery append method complete Structure. div is double tag element and when you write with single tag , jQuery add close tag. U can use html method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea... Let's see what happened every time you *append* something to the element.

```js
var divStep = $("#stepTab");
divStep.append('<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"><input type="checkbox" />Test</div>');
console.log(divStep.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stepTab"></div>
```

return `<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"><input type="checkbox">Test</div>`

```js
var divStep = $("#stepTab");
divStep.append('<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;">');
console.log(divStep.html());
divStep.append('<input type="checkbox" />Test');
console.log(divStep.html());
divStep.append('</div>');
console.log(divStep.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stepTab"></div>
```

it returns

**#1** `<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"></div>`

add `<div...left;">` **and `</div>` automatically**.

**#2** `<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"></div><input type="checkbox">Test`

**#3** `<div style="width:400px;height:40px;float:left;clear:left;"></div><input type="checkbox">Test`

nothing added.

---

**Conclusion:** I suppose that the string will be automatically turned into **a complete html element/object**, instead of appending the html string directly to the innerHTML of the parent node. Because `</div>` can't be turned into a html element since it is not a fully enclosed HTML, so nothing happened in #3 append.

Answer (score 0):

.appennd is not a native javascript function. its a jQuery method.

The append() method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements.

In your code append 3 won't work as you expected since it is not a fully enclosed HTML, but 3 sibling dom elements.